# Flashing taskbar using Java (a la pidgin || MSN)

Tags: java, taskbar

I'm looking for a push in the right direction. I have a simple chat program, written totally in Java, and am looking for a way to get the Taskbar icons to flash. Preferably in a manner similar to Pidgin, or MSN.

I'm hoping for a platform independent solution, as there are both Linux and Windows users, and preferably totally in Java.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45075/java-flash-a-window-to-grab-users-attention, although that question is about flashing the whole window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is unfortunately no way to do this in the standard Swing API. But you could work around it in several ways:

- Flash the icon and title of the window (set a timer and change them whenever it fires).
- Request focus, then immediately make the window invisible; reverse the process at your preferred interval.

Both techniques are demonstrated in [this forums.sun.com thread](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5302865).

Alternatively, instead of flashing, you could display a message in the system tray using [`TrayIcon.displayMessage()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/TrayIcon.html#displayMessage(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.awt.TrayIcon.MessageType)); that may or may not suit you better, but beware that it may not work cross-platform.